# Best practice for inheriting an object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I need an advice for the best practice in order to add behavior to an object received as a `json` object.

I have a `REST` services that allow me to define a sort of state machine.

The API define a `/sessions` resources. When creating a session via `POST /sessions/:id` I get an `json` object in my controller:

```
var session = {
   "id": "",
   "steps": [ ... ]
}
```

With this object I would like it to inherit some behavior:

```
var baseSession = {
  "nextStep": function() {... },
  "getCurrentStep": function() { ...}
}
```

So what I would like to do is:

```
session.__proto__ = baseSession;
```

But using `__proto__` seems not the thing to do.
The other possibility would be to duplicate every property in a new object:

```
function copyOwnProperyTo(origin, obj) {
     Object.keys(origin).forEach(function(prop) {
        obj[prop] = origin[prop];

    });
}
var newSession = Object.create(baseSession);
copyOwnProperyTo(session, newSession);
```

This solution work but to me it look a bit heave. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "proper" ES6 solution is to combine `Object.assign` with `Object.create`:

```
var session = Object.assign(Object.create(baseSession), {
   "id": "",
   "steps": […]
});
```

Of course you can also use your own copying method instead of `Object.assign`.

And finally, there is `Object.setPrototypeOf`, which could be used like

```
var session = Object.setPrototypeOf({
   "id": "",
   "steps": […]
}, baseSession);
```